# Why doesn't apt detect the newer .deb version in the universe repository, even though it exists there?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

I'm trying to figure out why doesn't `apt-get` detect the newer version of `chromium-browser`.

This is on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

First of all, this is the output of `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

This is the output of `apt-cache policy chromium-browser`:

```
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 73.0.3683.86-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 73.0.3683.86-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 73.0.3683.86-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 500
        500 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

It shows my installed version `73` as being the newest and it matches the candidate version, so it wouldn't update anything.

If I try to simulate the installation with `apt-get install -s chromium-browser`, I get:

```
chromium-browser is already the newest version (73.0.3683.86-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, there's a newer version `78` in the universe repository, in this folder:
http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/

Here's the link to the actual .deb I'm thinking of:
http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/chromium-browser_78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb

And here's a screenshot of the said folder for future readers when the above link becomes dead:

[image]

Also note that if I add this `ppa`...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-chromium-builds/stage
```

...then the output of `apt-cache policy chromium browser` is this:

```
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 73.0.3683.86-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
     78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-chromium-builds/stage/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 73.0.3683.86-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 500
        500 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Now it does see as the candidate the newer version `78`.

However, my question is **why doesn't it detect the version `78` from the universe repository**, and why do I even need to add the ppa, since I demonstrated above that the .deb exists.

Note: I'm not asking for instructions how to update a package - I know how to install a .deb file. Instead, I'm trying to understand how does the apt tool work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You have to enable *xenial-updates* and *xenial-security* in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` or on Updates tab of Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`).

---

It seems that you incorrectly understand the *pool* folder structure. It contains all packages for all releases.

You should go to https://packages.ubuntu.com and run search for [*chromium-browser* package amd64](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=amd64&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=chromium-browser) to determine correct versions for your current release.

Then you will get the following for *xenial* and *xenial-updates*:

> xenial (16.04LTS) (web): Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome [**universe**]
>   78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 [**security**]: amd64
>   xenial-updates (web): Chromium web browser, open-source version of Chrome [**universe**]
>   78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1: amd64

So you can get the latest possible package version from *universe* pocket:

> 78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1: amd64

On my fully updated system the output is the following:

`$ apt-cache policy chromium-browser
chromium-browser:
  Installed: 78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 78.0.3904.108-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages`

---

In your particular case it seems that *xenial-updates* is missed in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. You need to re-enable it from terminal or by visiting Updates tab of Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`) .

Also I need to note that current Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version is 16.04.6 LTS.
So really you need to enable *xenial-updates*, *xenial-security*, then update package lists with `sudo apt-get update` and install all newest dependencies with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. This will solve many security- and update- related problems.

Comment: You're right! In Software & Updates I had `Install updates from: Recommended updates (xenial-updates)` turned off. After turning it back on, `apt-cache` detects the newer version. So if I understand correctly: those versions in `xenial` I linked to apply if installing it for the very first time, right? But since I have it already installed, then it's searching in `xenial-updates`?

Comment: You have to enable these *xenial-updates* and *xenial-security* and then run `sudo apt-get update` to get new package lists. Also I highly recommend to run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get all new upgrades for your 16.04 LTS to upgrade it from 16.04.2 to the latest 16.04.6.

Answer (score 1):

> Hit:1 http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease

You are looking only in "xenial"?

This is the state, when xenial was released and xenial-updates contains the versions that were released later.

`http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/` shows `Contents-amd64.gz    2016-04-21 08:04` while `http://lu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/` has `Contents-amd64.gz  2019-12-11 05:57`

This file holds the information, which pakage is available in which version and all of them are downloadable from the "pool" tree.

In the file from "xenial" you only find `Version: 49.0.2623.108-0ubuntu1.1233`

So you have to add `xenial-updates` to your sources.list and should be able to update.

Comment: Yes, I understand now how it works: it takes from `xenial` if installing for the first time, and from a different folder `xenial-updates` if only updating. So those .deb files in `xenial` are not relevant for updating.